# Checked out branch in Rider but seeing different in the Terminal

Tags: terminal, branch, checkout, rider

This is my first ever question here. I'm new to my role (Junior Software Engineer) and I am the first to admit this is probably a stupid question.

So, I created and checked out a new branch in Rider IDE

[Rider branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkexN.png)

But when I check in the terminal I see my previously checked out branch

[Terminal branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9mB0.png)

Is there an obvious reason why this might be happening?

Many thanks in advance

I expected to see the same branch showing as the current one when checking both Rider and the Terminal

Comment: Welcome! Stupid question back  did you start the terminal after or before changing the branch?

Comment: @mu88 I'm pretty sure I had the Terminal already open while I created > checked out in Rider. So, before changing the branch (98% sure!). I can check that theory though!

Comment: Okay, if this is the case, then the situation is clear: consider the terminal's output to be a photograph: it's a snapshot of a moment in time, meaning that if you changed the branch after opening the terminal, it will not know about it and display the past. Solution: update the terminal with any command, e. g. `git branch --show-current`

Comment: Thanks buddy! I think this sorted it out - every day is a school day :-)

Comment: You're very welcome :) I'll provide it as an answer so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together, we figured it out and found the problem (see the comments). The issue was related to the fact that the terminal with the corresponding Git command was opened and executed **before** the branch change was triggered within the IDE.

The solution is easy: execute the shell command again after changing the branch.